# How to send initial metadata for a server stream in gRPC Python

Tags: python, grpc

I have a gRPC server that offers a server-streaming RPC. However, upon invocation of the RPC I'd like to send some metadata from the client to the server. I've found that you can use `with_call` with non-streaming RPCs (see [the metadata example on GitHub](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/1d2cce2449e39a846b59efb1805343efb9d5d3b9/examples/python/metadata/metadata_client.py#L31)).
This aparently doesn't work with streaming RPCs (you'd get an `AttributeError: '_UnaryStreamMultiCallable' object has no attribute 'with_call'`).

So, my question is, how can I send metadata along with a server-streaming RPC from the client to the server? Since the server can retrieve the invocation metadata there must be a way to send it from the client, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I found out how you can send metadata with a server-streaming RPC. The only thing you need to do is to add a tuple of tuples as parameter for the `metadata` keyword argument like so:

```py
stub.MyServerStreamingRPC(
    _pb2.MyServerStreamingRequest(),
    metadata=(('metadata-identifier', 'metadata-value'),)
#                                                      ^
)
```

The important thing here, if you're using just one metadata pair like me, is the comma after the first inner tuple. If you forget this, the argument to the `metadata` parameter is not recognized as a tuple and you'll get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.
I did forget this when I first tried to simply pass the additional `metadata` argument, which led me to believe that it wasn't as simple as I thought. But, as it turns out it is if you know how to use Python properly :D